# Closed the terminal window running the server, but upon trying to rerun the server is says port still in use

Tags: django

I ran `python manage.py runserver` and the website was running at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. I closed the terminal window running the server, reopened terminal and tried to run `python manage.py runserver` again, but it says `Error: That port is already in use`. I can't quit the server with `Control-C` like I normally do, so I am not sure what do to here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Windows or linux?

Comment: @Sahil uh... Mac OS? Not sure if that is linux based

Comment: Yeah it should work, just a sec.

Comment: `sudo lsof -i:22` change 22 with your port number,you'll get a PID , type `sudo kill PID`

Comment: @Sahil had feel asleep right after responding, but thanks!

Comment: no worries my man! apparently @bmons has already answered your question. Good luck in further development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps to  kill the server that's running.

```
$ lsof -i :8000
```

8000 is the port. So, if your using django and you run python manage.py runserver it's likely your port will be "8000"

That command will yield something like:

```
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python  1158   biju    3u  IPv4 0x4ae303085ae91559      0t0  TCP localhost:irdmi (LISTEN)
```

Except under "biju" it would have your username. Do you see the value under "PID" this is the number you need. Now you just kill that process.

```
$ kill -9 1158
```

Let's do that one more time:

```
$ lsof -i :8000

COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python  4894 biju    3u  IPv4 0x4ae3030864c1dd41      0t0  TCP localhost:irdmi (LISTEN)

$ kill -9 4894
```

And that's it. You can kill this server without an error running.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Appreciate you doing it twice, I was originally typing in 'kill -9 PID' and not the PID number